# Type hint for a reference to a generic function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, fp-ts

So in TS we have the generic identity function:

```js
const identity = <A>(a: A) => a;
```

Of course, if we invoke that function then TS is able to infer the type parameter `A`:

```js
declare const baz: string

const foo = identity("bar") // A = "bar", so typeof foo = "bar"
const bar = identity(baz) // A = string, so typeof bar = string
```

But if I try something like

```js
import { foldMap } from "fp-ts/Array"
import { getMonoidAll, Predicate } from "fp-ts/Predicate"

declare const predicates: Predicate<string>[];

const concatPredicates = foldMap(getMonoidAll<string>())(identity);
```

then TS tells me that "Type `A` is not assignable to type `Predicate<string>` because it infers

```js
typeof foldMap(getMonoidAll<string>()) = <A>(f: (a: A) => Predicate<string>) => 
(fa: A[]) => Predicate<string>
```

and it doesn't understand that if `A = Predicate<string>` then the identity function works and the construct above expects an input of type `Predicate<string>[]`.

Of course, instead of using `identity` I could use `(a: Predicate<string>) => a`, but having to do that feels a bit cumbersome and I would really love to be able to take advantage of the generic nature of the `identity` function.

Is there any way to do so? Is there any way I can provide a type hint for a function reference? After all, the unnaturally verbose looking `(a: Predicate<string>) => identity(a)` works because in that case TS infers `A = Predicate<string>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure why TypeScript can’t infer the type of `identity` correctly, but you could do this as a workaround:

```ts
const concatPredicates = foldMap(getMonoidAll<string>())(
  identity as (a: Predicate<string>) => Predicate<string>
);
```

Alternatively (and what I prefer for this scenario), you could use [`concatAll`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Monoid.ts.html#concatall):

```ts
import { concatAll } from "fp-ts/Monoid";

const concatPredicates = concatAll(getMonoidAll<string>());
```